# Name of this almost diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

I am guessing this type of matrix has a name:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_2 & d & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_3 & 0 & d & 0 & 0 \\
a_4 & 0 & 0 & d & 0 \\
a_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d
\end{pmatrix}$$

Can anyone tell me its name? It looks like its inverse is super simple but I'd rather look it up than derive it from scratch :D

Comment: You can check this it is very similar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Comment: Sort of but not really, right?

Comment: It is a companion matrix which has been transformed by elementary operations on rows and lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would likely class as a Frobenius matrix, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_matrix, where we have multiplied the matrix with $d$ and thus the $a_i = b_i / d$ for $d \neq 0$.