# Is there a name for this type of "almost diagonal" matrix?

Tags: matrices

I have a symmetric matrix $A\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$, for which the only $a_{ij}\neq0$ have $i=1$, $j=1$ or $i=j$. That is: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}d_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n\\a_2 & d_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\a_3 & 0 & d_3 & \cdots & 0\\\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\a_n & 0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n\end{pmatrix}\,.$$ Is there a name for this class of real-valued matrices (or the obvious extension to Hermitian matrices)? The closest I've found in my search is the class of Frobenius matrices, mentioned in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829516/name-of-this-almost-diagonal-matrix), but they aren't symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: it is called an [arrowhead matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix) (for obvious, appearance-related reasons).

**Edit:** what you specifically want is a *symmetric* arrowhead matrix.

Comment: Argh! beat me to it by 16 seconds.

Comment: That's not a lot of seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are discussing is referred to as an [Arrowhead matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix), or sometimes just "arrow" matrix. These are matrices with zeros everywhere except the first row, column and main diagonal.